# Inconsistant Results from Searchkick / Elasticsearch Aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

First off I will work on cleaning up the output from IRB (this was from production).

I was using some search kick aggregations in my Rails app.  tested fine in development now in production I am seeing inconsistent results.  I have data in fields that should clearly show up in my aggregations.

Here is my plain old Active Record Data - my `BudgetItem` model has a `total`:

```
irb(main):008:0> BudgetItem.where(budget_id: 3).order(:cbs_item_id).select(:id, :cbs_item_id, :total)
  BudgetItem Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "budget_items"."id", "budget_items"."cbs_item_id", "budget_items"."total" FROM "budget_items" WHERE "budget_items"."company_id" = 26 AND "budget_items"."budget_id" = $1 ORDER BY "budget_items"."cbs_item_id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["budget_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<BudgetItem id: 28, company_id: 26, cbs_item_id: 3, total: 0.1e5>, #<BudgetItem id: 29, company_id: 26, cbs_item_id: 12, total: 0.8e5>, #<BudgetItem id: 34, company_id: 26, cbs_item_id: 15, total: 0.1e5>, #<BudgetItem id: 41, company_id: 26, cbs_item_id: 16, total: 0.141e6>, #<BudgetItem id: 35, company_id: 26, cbs_item_id: 18, total: 0.1e5>, #<BudgetItem id: 33, company_id: 26, cbs_item_id: 18, total: 0.12e5>, #<BudgetItem id: 27, company_id: 26, cbs_item_id: 20, total: 0.2e5>, #<BudgetItem id: 6, company_id: 26, cbs_item_id: 23, total: 0.184e6>, #<BudgetItem id: 5, company_id: 26, cbs_item_id: 23, total: 0.2288e6>, #<BudgetItem id: 30, company_id: 26, cbs_item_id: 24, total: 0.45e5>, ...]>
```

The count on this is 41

the same search via Searchkick:

```
BudgetItem.search("*", where: {budget_id: 3}).count = 41
```

and even this:

```
irb(main):025:0> BudgetItem.search("*", where: {budget_id: 3, cbs_item_id: 16}).first.total
= 26 AND "budget_items"."id" = $1  [["id", 41]]
=> 0.141e6
```

Note `cbs_item_id: 16, total: 0.141e6` (141000) - the value is clearly in the model.

Now I try and run aggregates on this:

```
irb(main):019:0> BudgetItem.search("*", body_options: { aggs: { cbs: { terms: { field: "cbs_item_id" }, aggs: { "total": { "sum": { "field": "total" } } } } } },  where: {budget_id: 3}).aggs
  BudgetItem Search (5.4ms)  pacific-canbriam-20191213_budget_items_production/_search {"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match_all":{}},"filter":[{"term":{"budget_id":{"value":3}}}]}},"timeout":"11s","_source":false,"size":10000,"aggs":{"cbs":{"terms":{"field":"cbs_item_id"},"aggs":{"total":{"sum":{"field":"total"}}}}}}
=> {"cbs"=>{"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0, "sum_other_doc_count"=>13, "buckets"=>[{"key"=>24, "doc_count"=>4, "total"=>{"value"=>90000.0}}, {"key"=>25, "doc_count"=>4, "total"=>{"value"=>114000.0}}, {"key"=>39, "doc_count"=>4, "total"=>{"value"=>107325.0}}, {"key"=>43, "doc_count"=>4, "total"=>{"value"=>209820.0}}, {"key"=>18, "doc_count"=>2, "total"=>{"value"=>22000.0}}, {"key"=>23, "doc_count"=>2, "total"=>{"value"=>412800.0}}, {"key"=>38, "doc_count"=>2, "total"=>{"value"=>13500.0}}, {"key"=>49, "doc_count"=>2, "total"=>{"value"=>161000.0}}, {"key"=>57, "doc_count"=>2, "total"=>{"value"=>20300.0}}, {"key"=>58, "doc_count"=>2, "total"=>{"value"=>32200.0}}]}}
```

The data is completely inconsistent and aggs missing.  Note key 16 is missing.  The crazy thing is I have another aggregation on another column and that one works absolutely fine.  Am i missing something here? I have already tried `settings: {number_of_shards: 1}`.

To be more frustrating this works:

```
  aggs: {
    "grand_total": { "sum": { "field": "total"  } },
   }
```

The regular agg for `total` works in the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `size` in the aggregation. Based on `sum_other_doc_count` in the response, 13 documents aren't being returned.